# diff: show entire section based on indentation

Tags: linux, bash, diff, gnu

I'm working with the GNU diff utility to identify changes to configuration files (at this time we're only looking at Cisco ASAs and IOS devices). I need the ability to identify changes to a configuration group based on the level of indentation.

For instance, take this bit of configuration:

```
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
 network-object object Hyrule-DC02
 network-object object Hyrule-DC03
```

If the third line, "network-object object Hyrule-DC02" is removed then I want to print the entire group of configuration, beginning with the first line without indentation until the last line with indentation. In this example the lines I want to print would be:

```
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
 network-object object Hyrule-DC03
```

Here is an example of the code structure. This style of grouping by indentation is used throughout the config:

```
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2
 network-object object Hyrule-NS01-MGMT
 network-object object Hyrule-NS01-VIP1
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
 network-object object Hyrule-DC02
 network-object object Hyrule-DC03
```

Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if this example/question isn't clear enough.

Comment: You will need more than just gnu diff. You will want a whole scripting language of some sort. Awk or perl or even bash.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that SO is not a free coding service, you need to show your efforts. And please take the time to go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me sketch for you a solution based on common Unix tools.

- First process the file with *sed* to fold the indented lines of the two files into a a single line. Replace leading spaces with a control character.  For this you'll use *sed*'s `{`, `H`, `s`, and `p` commands.
- Then run *diff* on the two folded files, specifying that it's OK to process a binary file.
- Finally, run *sed* on the output of *diff* to unfold the output by replacing the control character with *diff*'s leading character (e.g. `<` or `>`), a newline, and indentation.  Here *sed*'s `s` command should be all you need.

Comment: This was very helpful. That was the direction I needed, thank you.